# Aligning an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image using CSS and Im pretty sure I am using the correct selector in CSS because I have resized the image, but I cant get it to align properly.

My HTML:

```
</br>
<div class="copyright">
  <em>TWO GREEN THUMBS 2013© ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</em>
</div>
</br>
<div class="sponsors">
  <a href="https://craneflight.org">
    <img src="https://greenthumbsfarm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CRANE-FLIGHT-COMP-2-1.jpg" alt="crane-flight-logo" class="thumb" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's what i tried for CSS:

```
.sponsors>img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.sponsors>img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img.thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
</br>
<div class="copyright">
  <em>TWO GREEN THUMBS 2013© ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</em>
</div>
</br>
<div class="sponsors">
  <a href="https://craneflight.org">
    <img src="https://greenthumbsfarm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CRANE-FLIGHT-COMP-2-1.jpg" alt="crane-flight-logo" class="thumb" />
  </a>
</div>
```

and

```
.sponsors>img.align-center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```css
.sponsors>img.align-center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
img.thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
</br>
<div class="copyright">
  <em>TWO GREEN THUMBS 2013© ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</em>
</div>
</br>
<div class="sponsors">
  <a href="https://craneflight.org">
    <img src="https://greenthumbsfarm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CRANE-FLIGHT-COMP-2-1.jpg" alt="crane-flight-logo" class="thumb align-center" />
  </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the image to align at the bottom of the page below where it says "TWO GREEN THUMBS 2013© ALL RIGHTS RESERVED", but I just can't figure it out. I have looked through multiple similar questions and none of the other solutions seem to be working in this case. Could it be I am not using the selector properly?

EDIT: I have the image resized with the "thumb" class selector because there will be several images and they will all need to be the same size. Here's the code:

```
img.thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a code snippet, or a jsFiddle with an example? Thanks

Comment: Side note, `</br>` is incorrect. Use either `<br>` or `<br />`

Comment: is that image suppose to be resized ?  It does not seem clear to me. :)

Comment: @GCyrillus The image is resized through CSS with the class selector "thumb". It's a standard size I use on the site. I am looking for a horizontal alignment. Sorry, I should have specified. If it makes it easier the site is https://greenthumbsfarm.com I am trying to get the image at the bottom, the one that says "CRANE FLIGHT", to align in the center. In the future I will add more img links there and would like them all to line up at the bottom. Those are sponsors of the company.

Comment: @N.Ivanov Im not sure how to do that. It is a wordpress site so I think I only have the option to add snippet to the site through a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to apply the style to the container DIV.

```
.sponsors {
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: try smaller image, it worked here with your code.... try to add `!important`, and use `.sponsors` selector not `.sponsors>img`, let me know

Comment: the image is only 100px*150px. I have it resized with the "thumb" class selector. I posted the code above in the op.

Comment: please try with your developer tool, chrome F12, and try to see which style is overriding the center tag for .sponsors selectors, try removing all styles on div and apply one by one from dev tool.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to aligning it with the div:

```
<div class="sponsors" align="center">
<a href="https://craneflight.org">
<img src="https://greenthumbsfarm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CRANE-FLIGHT-COMP-2-1.jpg" alt="crane-flight-logo" class="thumb"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, but I would prefer to do it through CSS. I will settle for this for now though if I can't find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I added a container around both elements and made that an inline-block (so it would be only the width of its contents and stay left) .
Then I centered the image inside that container by applying `text-align-center` to the `.sponsors` DIV . I also centered the top line to be center aligned with the image using `text-align: center`.

BTW: You had a wrong CSS selector for the image. There is an `a` tag between the div and the image, so `.sponsors>img` won't have any effect. Either `.sponsors>a>img` or just `.sponsors img`

```css
.container1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

.sponsors {
  text-align: center;
}

.sponsors img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="copyright">
    <em>TWO GREEN THUMBS 2013© ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</em>
  </div>

  <div class="sponsors">
    <a href="https://craneflight.org">
      <img src="https://greenthumbsfarm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CRANE-FLIGHT-COMP-2-1.jpg" alt="crane-flight-logo" class="thumb" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have said this before, but I have the image resized through CSS. I'll edit my post and add that code now.

Comment: Nevertheless, the rest of my answer still applies (wrong CSS selector, centering of image and text line)

Comment: please note my changed snipppet

Comment: I want the "copyright" text to stay where it is, but it's still not working even with that selector. I posted the code I used to resize the img above in the op.

Comment: then you have to put them both into a container - I'll add that in a minute

Comment: The copyright text is supposed to be separate from the sponsors.

Comment: That's a contradiction to your question "I am trying to get the image to align at the bottom of the page below where it says "TWO GREEN THUMBS 2013© ALL RIGHTS RESERVED","

Comment: Sorry. I worded that badly. I just want the image centered and it needs to be below that text. Not directly below or aligned with it. I was just specifying that it needs to be below that line.